# What form(s) of radiation are least attenuated by the atmosphere?

Tags: atmospheric-science, attenuation

Given the composition of Earth's atmosphere, what is the most efficient way of wirelessly beaming energy from the stratosphere down to the surface?

Comment: Neutrinos would be good. Creating and capturing them is the hard bit.

Comment: Yes, production cost of the radiation will have to be considered as well

Comment: You might start at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-based_solar_power